# Extension of a continuous map on $ {\mathbf{GL}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $ to $ {\mathbf{M}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, matrices, continuity

I was reading in my analysis textbook that the map $ f: {\mathbf{GL}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) \to {\mathbf{GL}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $ defined by $ f(A) := A^{-1} $ is a continuous map. I also saw that $ {\mathbf{GL}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $ is dense in $ {\mathbf{M}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $. My question is:

> What is the unique extension of $ f $ to $ {\mathbf{M}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $?

Comment: $GL_n(R)$ is not a closed subset. So, continuous function defined on $GL_n(R)$ may not be extended to $M_n(R)$. Indeed in this case, cannot be. It is almost like asking "what is an inverse matrix of noninvertible matrix?"

Comment: Akt904, I guess you were thinking of using the Tietze Extension Theorem?

Comment: yes I was but i forgot that the subset needed to be closed

Comment: @Akt904 which Analysis Book it is? could you tell me the writer name?

Comment: A uniformly continuous function out of a dense subset of a metric space may be extended to a uniformly continuous function out of the whole space (simply define $f(\lim~x_n)=\lim f(x_n)$ everywhere). This might be the intuition you were operating on. The inverse map is not uniformly continuous though.

Comment: Consider the case $n = 1$: $\mathbf{GL}_1(\mathbb R) = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ and $x^{-1} = \frac{1}{x}$. Is this map continuously extendible to $\mathbf{M}_1(\mathbb R) = \mathbb R$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrices

$$ A_{n} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{n} & 0\\ 0 & \frac{1}{n} \end{pmatrix}$$

converge to the zero matrix as $n \to \infty$. Their inverses are

$$ A_{n} = n \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

And this goes to infinity in matrix norm as $n\to \infty$. Thus there is no way to extend the inverse to even the zero matrix.

This example is analogous to trying to extend $f(x) = x^{-1}$ from $(0,1)$ to $[0,1]$.

Comment: Hi Isaac...If you have time can you explain how this answers the question? I dont understand it.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by the others, you cannot extend $f$ to a *continuous* function $g:M_n(\mathbb{R})\to M_n(\mathbb{R})$, because there exists a convergent sequence of invertible matrices $X_n$ such that $f(X_n)=X_n^{-1}$ diverges. There does exist, however, a *bijective* function $g:M_n(\mathbb{R})\to M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $g=f$ on $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, namely, $g(X)=X^+$ is the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) of $X$.

Comment: Simpler one could define $g(A)=A$ for non-invertible $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the two answers above. If you refer to my solution in the thread [Left topological zero-divisors in Banach algebras.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290971/left-topological-zero-divisors-in-banach-algebras/291196#291196), you will see that if $ X \in \partial({\text{GL}_{n}}(\mathbb{R})) \subseteq {\text{M}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $, where $ \partial $ denotes the topological boundary operator, then there exists a sequence $ (X_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ in $ {\text{GL}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $ such that $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} X_{n} = X $ but $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \| X_{n}^{-1} \| = \infty $. This proves that $ (\bullet)^{-1}: {\text{GL}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) \to {\text{GL}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $ cannot be extended continuously to $ {\text{M}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $.